# Como colocar um delay, dentro de uma função no R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Olá! 
Eu gostaria de colocar um atraso, dentro de uma função que estou criando para juntar N-gráficos. Percebi que em algumas casos, minha função não espera o `eval(parse(text=paste()))` gerar todas as listas, e já pula para a próxima linha de código dentro da função. ( Eu uso o `eval(parse(text)))`para gerar sequências de linhas executáveis, pois as vezes preciso retornar a uma informação dentro de algum objeto, o que por falta de conhecimento meu, não consigo realizar usando algum `loop`).

Infelizmente, a função que resulta no erro, é muito extensa, e o erro só aparece ao utilizar a base de dados completa, por isso, criei uma função genérica para tentar explicar, onde entraria o **atraso**.

**Pacotes utilizados:**

```
pacs<-{
  pacotes<-c("ggplot2","ggpmisc","ggpubr")
    eval(parse(text=paste('if(!require(',pacotes,')){install.packages("',pacotes,'")}',sep="")))
}
```

**Base de dados**

```
base<-structure(list(FAT1=c("T19","T19","T19","T19","T19","T19",
"T19","T19","T19","T19","T19","T19","T19","T19","T19",
"T19","T19","T19","T19","T19","T19","T19","T19","T19"
),VARY=c(0.626,0.299,0.658,0.954,0.52,0.445,0.61,0.649,
0.348,0.599,0.338,0.295,0.589,0.449,0.522,0.76,0.664,
0.416,0.522,0.512,0.353,0.623,0.563,0.249),VARX=c(0.631,
0.3,0.635,0.933,0.514,0.466,0.572,0.653,0.348,0.605,
0.345,0.273,0.597,0.457,0.516,0.748,0.684,0.432,0.532,
0.517,0.351,0.633,0.581,0.227)),class="data.frame",row.names=c(NA,
24L))
```

**Função:**

```
plota.tudo<-function(base,N){
  minha.formula<-y~I(x)+I(x^2)+I(x^3)

  eq<-function(minha.formula){
    stat_poly_eq(formula = minha.formula,eq.with.lhs = "italic(hat(Y))~`=`~",aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label..,  sep =  "*plain(\",\")~")), parse = TRUE)}

  eval(parse(text=paste('graf',1:N,'<-ggplot(base,aes(x=VARX,y=VARY))+geom_point()+geom_smooth(formula=minha.formula,method = "lm",se=FALSE,color="black",span=.8)+eq(minha.formula)',sep="")))
  # Local para haver o atraso!!! 
  # pois eu preciso que ele crie todos os arquivos de graficos
  eval(parse(text=paste('grafico<-annotate_figure(ggarrange(graf1,',paste(paste('graf',2:N,sep=""),c(rep(",",N-2),""),collapse=" ",sep=""),
                        ', common.legend = T),',
                        'left = text_grob("VARIAVEL X",rot=90,size = 12),',
                        'bottom = text_grob("VARIAVEL Y",size=12))',sep="")))
  print(grafico)}

# plota.tudo(base,N=quantidade de graficos a ser gerada)

plota.tudo(base,10)
```

Comment: Sobre o código, eu verificaria a necessidade de atribuir os gráficos como objeto meados dinamicamente e não apenas retorná-los numa lista com `purrr::map()` ou algo do tipo

Comment: As situações em que realmente precisamos usar `eval(parse(text = ...))` são muito raras

Comment: Veja se `aes_string()` não pode lhe ajudar a descomplicar o código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função que inclui um intervalo entre a execução de um comando e de outro no `R` é `Sys.sleep()`. O argumento passado é o tempo, em segundos, que o `R` deve "dormir".

```
plota.tudo<-function(base,N){
  minha.formula<-y~I(x)+I(x^2)+I(x^3)

  eq<-function(minha.formula){
    stat_poly_eq(formula = minha.formula,eq.with.lhs = "italic(hat(Y))~`=`~",aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label..,  sep =  "*plain(\",\")~")), parse = TRUE)}

  eval(parse(text=paste('graf',1:N,'<-ggplot(base,aes(x=VARX,y=VARY))+geom_point()+geom_smooth(formula=minha.formula,method = "lm",se=FALSE,color="black",span=.8)+eq(minha.formula)',sep="")))
  # Local para haver o atraso!!! 
  # pois eu preciso que ele crie todos os arquivos de graficos
  Sys.sleep(1)

  eval(parse(text=paste('grafico<-annotate_figure(ggarrange(graf1,',paste(paste('graf',2:N,sep=""),c(rep(",",N-2),""),collapse=" ",sep=""),
                        ', common.legend = T),',
                        'left = text_grob("VARIAVEL X",rot=90,size = 12),',
                        'bottom = text_grob("VARIAVEL Y",size=12))',sep="")))
  print(grafico)
}
```

Não testei sua função, já que ela não era objeto da pergunta, apenas inclui o intervalo de um segundo no local indicado.